# How would I get to increment the set timeout to apply to each classname pause?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout, getelementsbyclassname

I need help trying to increment my for loop so after 8 seconds my divs show not just one. I would prefer vanilla js if possible.

I have tried doing my own for loop and settimeout I have failed.

```
var googleAds = document.getElementsByClassName('pause');
var i;
for(var i = 0; i < googleAds.length; i++) { 
    setTimeout(function () {
    googleAds[i].style.display = "block";
}, 8000);
 }
```

isplaying after 8 seconds

Comment: Do you want them to show up 8 seconds after the previous element and not all at the same time?

Comment: I want to show them all at the same time once that 8 seconds has hit. I want to know what is the best way to do this I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the for loop inside the anonymous function for `i` to be in scope:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  for(var i = 0; i < googleAds.length; i++) { 
    googleAds[i].style.display = "block";
  }
}, 8000);
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me.